# C++ Copy constructor for binary tree with parent nodes

Tags: c++, binary-tree, deep-copy

I need to write a copy constructor for a binary tree class that makes a deep copy of given binary tree, but I always run into segmentation fault error when I execute my copy constructor, more specifically, the parent node is causing the problem, but I couldn't figure out the correct way of doing it.

```
class Node
{
 public:
  int value;;
  Node();
  Node(int v);
  Node * left;
  Node * right;
  Node * parent;
};
Node::Node()
{
  left=nullptr;
  right=nullptr;
  parent=nullptr;
  value=0;
}
Node::Node(int v)
{
  val = v;
  left = nullptr;
  right = nullptr;
  parent = nullptr;
}


class BT
{
  public:
   BT();
   BT(const BTr & t);
   Node *root;
   int size;
   Node * copy(Node *p);
   //other functions..
};

BT::BT()
{
  root = nullptr;
  size = 0;
}

//No need to consider if t.root is nullptr here
//assume t is always a non-empty valid binary tree here
BT::BT(const BT &t)
{
   size = t.size;
   root = copy(t.root); 
}

Node * BT::copy(Node *p)
{
  if (p == nullptr)
  {
    return nullptr;
  }
  Node * n = new TNode(p->val);
  n->left = copy(p->left);
  n->left->parent = n;
  n->right = copy(p->right);
  n->right->parent = n;
  return n;
}


int main()
{
  BT y;
  y.root = new Node(11);
  y.root->left = new Node(12);
  y.root->right = new Node(13);
  y.root->left->left = new Node(14);
  y.root->left->right = new Node(15);
  y.root->right->left = new Node(16);
  y.root->left->parent = y.root;
  y.root->right->parent = y.root;
  y.root->parent = nullptr;
  y.root->left->left->parent = y.root->left;
  y.root->left->right->parent = y.root->left;
  y.root->right->left->parent = y.root->right;
  y.size = 6;
  BT b(y);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n->left->parent = n;
n->right->parent = n;
```

You're performing these assignments without first checking whether any of `left` or `right` is `nullptr`.

Add the check:

```
if(n->left) n->left->parent = n;
```

And identically for `right`.

Comment: Initialized to what? If `p->left` is null, `n->left` is set to null as well. That's how copying works.

Comment: How would you fix this issue?

Comment: Apparently, check if `left` or `right` is null before dereferencing it to set its `parent`. :-o